# DataProvider in C# unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to create some data provider in C#. I DO NOT want to connect the DB, just to provide some values.
Is there any way of doing the following in C# - Microsoft Unit tests (The code was taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/))

```
@Test(dataProvider = "Data-Provider-Function")
public void parameterIntTest(TestNGTest6_3_0 clzz) {
     System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + clzz.getMsg());
     System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + clzz.getNumber());
}

//This function will provide the patameter data
@DataProvider(name = "Data-Provider-Function")
public Object[][] parameterIntTestProvider() {

    TestNGTest6_3_0 obj = new TestNGTest6_3_0();
    obj.setMsg("Hello");
    obj.setNumber(123);

    return new Object[][]{
        {obj}
    };
}
```

Comment: "@Test" ? That looks like java to me, not C# :)

Comment: Yes there is something like that in C#. It is called a DataSource to which you can provide a source string which can be an excel file or a DB. If you want some normal data, then just go ahead and put it in a text file and add to the Datasource as a CSV. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.aspx

Comment: What testing framework are you using? NUnit has a [TestCase] that could help with this. http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5

Comment: For now I am using the unit test framework which comes directly with visual studio. If there is some unit testing framework which can provide those features I can try it. 

The problem with values which are written in text file are that are static, I am trying to set some dynamic values.